# Blur a part of the background image css

Tags: html, css, blur

What's the best way to blur out the first 70px of my background image? The background image is in the body and I have a menubar with .08 opacity that I want to blur the background with. What's the best way and how do I do it?

Comment: Blur *top* 70px or *left* 70px?

Comment: @Jonathan hey, nice name! (My name's Jonathan aswell ;)) My menu-bar stretches to the whole width, so center top, I guess.

Comment: No, my name is Jeff. Anyways, see my answer. It actually turned out a lot better than I expected. I hope it helps! (and jk about my name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can achieve the same effect with javascript - *CSS is better* -
as shown in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/1fkt6wrt/)

```js
var blurredDiv = document.createElement('div');
blurredDiv.className = 'blurry';
document.body.appendChild(blurredDiv);
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image:url('//cdn01.wallconvert.com/_media/wallpapers_2880x1800/1/4/silver-bmw-i8-39331.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
.blurry {
    width:calc(100% + 6px);
    height:73px;
    position:fixed;
    top:-3px;
    left:-3px;
    background-image:url('//cdn01.wallconvert.com/_media/wallpapers_2880x1800/1/4/silver-bmw-i8-39331.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:0 3px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

Where the following CSS lines:

```
width:calc(100% + 6px);
height:73px;
position:fixed;
top:-3px;
left:-3px;
background-position:0 3px;
```

in the class of the blurred `70px` div is just a work around so that the blur effect will not affect the top and sides, the `background-position:0 3px;` is set for shifting the background image down by `3px` because we set the `top:-3px` to the `.blurry` div

Comment: That's a fancy image you got there ... and I would upvote as a good alternative, but I've used up my daily votes =(

Comment: Actually I've upvoted your answer as it is the better one, but this one i posted just with a work around for the unwanted blur effect on the left, right and the top sides

Comment: I pretty much did the same thing in my update. See update and explanation.

Comment: That does the trick with covering everything equally to the edges but I'm very unfamiliar with javascript combined with website-building so I have no idea how to implement this hahaha

Comment: @Condolent, you don't need the javascript part, take Jonathan's answer as the better solution for your problem, but just add the extra css shown separately and add it to the `::before` css in jonathan answer

Answer (score 4):

You can create a pseudo-element on top of that menu-bar (with `::before`; or you can create a regular element, but that's more cumbersome), with a height of 70px and width of 100% (the blurred area size). Then, you can set its background to the same as the menu-bar, but blurred.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://www.opaletch.co.uk/photos/rotating-patterns/p1921ri7pv1bb41m95du15sa1ce55.jpg);
}
div::before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-image: url(http://www.opaletch.co.uk/photos/rotating-patterns/p1921ri7pv1bb41m95du15sa1ce55.jpg);
    filter: blur(20px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
    -moz-filter: blur(20px);
    -o-filter: blur(20px);
    -ms-filter: blur(20px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

*changed image to show better the blurring effect*

*note: the edges don't blur as much because of the blurring algorithm, but it's minor*

See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ttumsmom/) on JSfiddle.

---

By request, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ttumsmom/3) is a solution to create "sharp" blur-area edges.

It is more complex, and requires you to define a second `<div>` and create a blur the background *inside* the *inner* `<div>`. But the pseudo-element inside the inner `<div>` is larger than the inner div, so the messy borders will be hidden. It's a bit difficult to explain, so look at the example.

Comment: Nice answer but i would suggest a better background as the blurring is not much clear in your example

Comment: Nice call @Akshay I'll change it.

Comment: Smart one, i was about to make the same with javascript, but yours is much better since it is pure css

Comment: That blurred it and all, but how would I make it so the whole div is blurred? I mean so that it's blurred to all the edges equally

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/3e05835ecb6d646bd57c453873d6bd23.png <- there's a screenshot of how it looks atm. I want the whole area of a light-white to be blurred all equally, reaching the edges if you know what I mean

Comment: @Condolent Okay, I'll figure something out.

Comment: You linked the same example, it's not updated for me :P

Comment: @Condolent oops, I've updated it now.

Comment: The overflow doesn't seem to be hidden, the actual blur-part is seemingly 10 pixels lower than the top bar, I've set the position of the blur-div to absolute since I have some other divs over that one. This is how it looks like atm https://i.gyazo.com/a7ac8540b9ac64cacd946fa5490731d9.png

EDIT: I put the top: 0; to the wrong div.. hehe. But it seems like it's not equally blurred everywhere, am I wrong? http://angryviking.teamcowgames.net

Comment: EDIT 2; solved it all by just making the size of the blur bigger. But with the top:0; and left: 0; (so it's correctly positioned) the whole background is now a bit too much to the left...